# Get data grid view row bound to entity

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I have an entity set bound to a DataGridView where users can add/modify rows. When validating entries made by the user I want to highlight grid view rows with errors. The problem is that as I loop through the list of entities I cannot find which row is bound to the entity I am validating.

How would I go about solving this issue (with C# or VB.NET)?

Comment: I tried foreach looping through the entity set and checking for a PK that is also in the DGV as a column but this does not work on newly added items. I suspect I need to use bindingcontext but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the item bound to a DataGridViewRow by its [DataBoundItem property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx). So you can loop through the rows and do the validations per row.

Comment: I wanted to loop through the data source and not the rows of the DataGrid.

Comment: Sure, but you'll have to make the match somehow and that's where DataBoundItem is useful.